# Fastest allocating and deallocating of many fixed lengths?

Tags: c++, memory, boost, heap-memory, allocation

I am creating a dynamically typed programming language and I need to resolve how I will allocate memory for the objects. Every size of an object is a multiple of 8 and is guranteed to be bigger than 16. I have tried malloc() and new but it is really slow. The code will run on 1 thread.

Basically, I will need support for objects of size 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 64, 72, 80, 96, you get the idea.

I have tried using std::pmr::memory_resource classes but I hope I can do better performance wise.

One thing I thought about is maintain a vector of fixed-sized-allocators, where every allocator handles 1 size, and when requesting I go to that allocator.

Comment: What you need is a custom heap allocator.  Allocate a block of memory, and then suballocate it with your own allocation logic.

Comment: Who uses `malloc` in C++? "But it was very slow" How did you use it? What is "slow"?

Comment: Right. Is there any reference implementation I can look at or even just the theory of it? Of course it would be better if there is anything like that in the std lib / boost.

Comment: @sehe I meant the new operator generally, they do the same thing really expect when you overload the new operator.

Comment: Here are some open source heap routines: [allocator](https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/allocator)

Answer (score 1):

If it is objects your'e dealing with, why don't use an object pool (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), perhaps templated so that you can have different pools for different object types. You should be able to reserve/allocate & free/deallocate at a rate of at least 1 GObjects/s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Unfortunately I heard it doesn't return back to the system, which I do need to return a bit memory from time to time.